# PHP Instagram API always return 'No matching code found.'

Tags: php, api, instagram

i Googled around but could not find the right answer! Thought it would be from my end or is it from Instagram?

1. Login to Instagram and access granted then redirect back to return URL with the code
2. API returns user details for the first time but when I refresh the page the API is always return 'No matching code found'?

I store the return instagram code as a session:

Instagram API class from: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

```
if ( isset($_GET['code']) ) {
   $_SESSION['instagram'] = $_GET['code'];

   $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($_SESSION['instagram']);

   if ( $data->code == 400 ) {
        echo $data->error_message;
    } else {
        echo 'Your username is: ' . $data->user->username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, what you describe is correct. On both ends. This is not an error in the API and as in the second request you didn't authenticate (again), there is also no code. It just works as intended. What you probably want to do is to store the code and use it in any non-first request by creating a session with the user.

Comment: Have you tried using `session_start()` at the top of your page?

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r will it not work if code is stored as session?

Comment: @tonoslfx I know this is quite old, but I had this problem recently and what I found out is that the code is valid only within the request. So you could not refresh http://yourdomain.com/redirect.php?code=some_code here. More than that you should make a request to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token in order to get the access_token of a user, then store the access_token in the session and use it. Hope it helps